Problem is related to running the next-app for very first time
I am new to Nextjs and getting an error while running the app for very first time only.... it also takes much time while installtion too the command i use for installation is "npx create-next-app@latest" and to run "num run dev" i am getting an error at compilation phase.
the error im getting is:
enter image description here
i tried running me next next app installed using npx create-next-app@latest but when i run it using npm run dev i am getting an error in compilation

Looks like the package tailwindcss-animate is missing from package.json. Try restarting server after installing the package.
npm install -D tailwindcss-animate

